# Intellij apparently not getting installed, not running

Tags: intellij-idea, fedora, 32-bit

i have a 32 bit Fedora 14 machine and I am trying to install IntellIJ IDEA on it, I used the package manager to install it. Along with that installation, also Eclipse and Groovy got installed.

Then I tried to install a new version of JDK but it didnt allow me to do so because of conflict with an older version of JRE, So I removed the JRE older version and installed JDK.

Then I have been noticing that IntelliJ refuses to run, I uninstalled and reinstalled and checked several times, but it just refuses to start, Then I opened a terminal and typed intell, hoping that the terminal would complete it for me, and I could launch the program from the command line, but no it said "intellIj:Command not found", whereas the same thing does not happen with Eclipse or Groovy.

I have tried restarting the machine several times, uninstalled and then reinstalled the packages several times, but nothing seems to work. I am not sure whether Intellij is getting  installed or not, but the Package Manager does not show any error while the software is being installed. Any ideas as to why this is happening, and how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to install it manually by just extracting tgz file downloaded from producer website. Then you start IDE by launching `IDEA_DIRECTORY/bin/idea.sh`